# how to store structures in an array of pointers using a template

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, pointers, struct

Ok, my pointer skills are a little poor. Im creating my own simple map container where different data types can be stored. Im trying to create the `insertPair()` method where a struct is stored in an array of pointers but i'm struggling with the syntax. I've created a structure and im trying to assign the value of `a` to `temp.key` and `b` to `temp.value`. how do i do this and store the structure in the array of pointers? ive created a`test` object in `main()` and passed in an `int` and a `string`. Any guidance greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
template <typename K, typename V>
class CMyMap
{
    int arraysize;
    CMyMap* myArr[5];
public:

    struct pair
    {
        K key;
        V value;
    };

    CMyMap()
    {
        arraysize = 0;
    }

    void insertPair(K a, V b)
    {
        pair* temp = new pair;
        temp->key = a;
        temp->value = b;

        myArr[0] = temp; // trying to store the values of temp.key and temp.value to myArr[0]
    }

    void display()
    {
        // dont how to display the key and value correctly.
        cout << myArr[0] << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    CMyMap<int, string> test;

    test.insertPair(23, "bob");

    test.display();

    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Several problems: What is `map`? Why do you have a method named `map()` without a return type? You've declared a pointer but you're accessing methods using the `.` operator when it should be `->`. Inside the constructor you're declaring a new variable instead of modifying the data member. `temp` is a pointer to a pair but you're assigning it to an array of *`map*`* to which it isn't compatible...

Comment: sorry, i changed the class name without updating it for the constructor. ive revised the code. (map was the old class name)

Answer (score 0):

`temp.key = a;` should be `temp->key = a;`.

Similarly, `temp.value` should be `temp->value`.

To get or set the value at index `i` in `*myArr`, you would use `(*myArr)[i]` since `myArr` is a pointer to an array.